# When can you rely on the value of this.state in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, going through the tutorial on the React website. In the step by step tutorial, there is a section which explains that you should not rely on the value of state for calculating the next state, because state updates are asynchronous. Instead, they explain, you should use a version of setState that accepts a function to which the previous state is passed as an argument.

However, in the practical tutorial, the following code appears:

```
handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      squares: squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
  }
```

in which the setState call passes an object that relies on a value from this.state. Why is this code ok and why would one not have to worry about asynchronous setState execution in this case? I'm trying to understand when exactly I can rely directly on the value of this.state in my React code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial's explanation is wrong. There are many cases in which you can rely on referencing `this.state` directly, including the case in the code snippet.

Referencing `this.state` directly is a problem *only if*

- You have previously called `this.setState` with the component, and
- The component hasn't rerendered yet, and
- You want to call `this.setState` again, while taking into account the value that was just set

If any of the above conditions are false, it's just fine to set the state by referencing `this.state` without using the callback version.

For example, in the snippet in your question, I'd presume that `handleClick` is a click handler, and no other click handlers run - a different state setter does not get called before you call `this.setState({ squares ...`, so there's no problem.

It *would* be problematic if you called multiple `handleClick`s in sequence, though. For example, if you had something like

```
handleMultipleClicks() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    handleClick(i);
  }
}
```

The above would be a problem, because you're calling `this.setState` multiple times before giving the component a chance to re-render; the `this.state.squares` that gets referenced in the second (and further) iterations of the loop would not reflect the value passed to `this.setState` in the first iteration of the loop.

One way to think of it is: `this.state` will reference the state at the end of the last re-render. If you write your code with that in mind, you'll be able to reliably determine whether you need to use the callback version of the state setter or not.

Comment: "`this.state` will reference the state at the end of the last re-render" ... Is this behavior due to batching of state updates? Thanks

Comment: While state updates are batched in some circumstances, that's not really *why* - I think it's the other way around. React doesn't reassign `this.state` until after synchronous handlers complete and React is ready to re-render. This incidentally allows for the optimization of re-renders by re-rendering only once, while taking into account multiple `setState` calls, but that batching optimization is more an optimization that builds on top of the more fundamental behavior, rather than being fundamental behavior itself.

Comment: @ CertainPerformance The Doc says that "If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form". So, it's just a recommendation, is the way you explain in this answer 100% guaranteed?

Comment: @TheProgrammer Yes, guaranteed. Very frequently, the next state depends on the current state, but the callback form is unnecessary. Perhaps a more blunt version of what they were recommending would be: "If you don't understand enough about React to know when `this.state` will update, use the callback version instead, which will always work."

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are not using the state immediately after `setState` hence it works as expected. Consider this example where you can get some unexpected results due to asynchronous state updates.

```js
handleClick(i) {
  console.log(this.state.value); // 1, can be any value
  this.setState({
    value: this.state.value + 1
  });
  console.log(this.state.value); // This is still 1, or the prev value
}
```

Also, it seems like you are using `Class` components so the tutorials might be very old. I would also suggest you learn functional components and hooks. It will make your life easier :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The tutorials do indeed use Class components, which I see from reading online that the community is largely moving away from. Interesting that such an outdated feature would be part of the official React tutorial at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html and in the guide in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.
Would you happen to have any recs for a good source to read up on functional components and hooks, or would you say the React docs themselves https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html are my best bet?

Comment: I always recommend reading official docs. React docs for hooks (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are decent but if you face any difficulty then there are some good tutorials available on Youtube. You can start with `useState` and `useEffect` hooks as they are most frequently used.

Comment: @ PR7 Is the problem then only when you call setState() and then want to build another state thinking that setState() already brings the new value?

Comment: @TheProgrammer This is a very common problem. Another issue is render blocking as explained by CertainPerformance in the accepted answer.